# I am working on phonegap wrapper WITH IFRAME for android. But in this file download functionality is not working. What to do?

Tags: android, file, cordova, iframe, download

1.Made PhoneGap wrapper.
2.loaded website with an iframe in android. 
3.file download functionality is not working.
please guide me to have a solution as soon as possible